# Plotting a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the form

```
Region Name     3-15    4-15    5-15    ...    3-16   

 Name1          30      82      56    ...      32
 Name2          65      23      38    ...      11
   ...         ...     ...     ...    ...     ...
Name18          87      33      11    ...      51
```

The first column being the names of regions and the other columns being recorded events over time (monthly by column)

I'd like to plot the recorded monthly values over time with respect to their associated name. Specifically, a different line for each Named region with a differentiated colour. Any advice would be appreciated, a lot of the plotting functions for data frames seem to function on frames of a different format.

```
dput() data:    
dataframe <- structure(list("LSOA Name" = c("Lancaster 001", "Lancaster 002", 
"Lancaster 003", "Lancaster 004", "Lancaster 005", "Lancaster 006", 
"Lancaster 008", "Lancaster 009", "Lancaster 010", "Lancaster 011", 
"Lancaster 013", "Lancaster 014", "Lancaster 015", "Lancaster 016", 
"Lancaster 017", "Lancaster 018", "Lancaster 019", "Lancaster 020"
), "3-15" = c(49L, 16L, 17L, 28L, 21L, 197L, 57L, 143L, 78L, 
121L, 67L, 223L, 41L, 86L, 66L, 27L, 40L, 77L), "4-15" = c(63L, 
11L, 26L, 29L, 19L, 203L, 69L, 154L, 82L, 125L, 62L, 198L, 44L, 
99L, 64L, 26L, 42L, 99L), "5-15" = c(67L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 
194L, 62L, 186L, 61L, 110L, 75L, 273L, 29L, 126L, 92L, 34L, 41L, 
88L), "6-15" = c(58L, 8L, 18L, 36L, 29L, 198L, 62L, 167L, 83L, 
110L, 59L, 254L, 26L, 99L, 73L, 17L, 30L, 109L), "7-15" = c(53L, 
29L, 27L, 23L, 38L, 188L, 56L, 149L, 90L, 129L, 37L, 226L, 32L, 
119L, 57L, 14L, 30L, 96L), "8-15" = c(44L, 9L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 
237L, 69L, 171L, 78L, 108L, 45L, 261L, 22L, 103L, 68L, 33L, 35L, 
108L), "9-15" = c(59L, 12L, 18L, 35L, 19L, 230L, 45L, 128L, 74L, 
144L, 56L, 223L, 26L, 90L, 51L, 27L, 23L, 120L), "10-15" = c(45L, 
26L, 31L, 23L, 25L, 195L, 53L, 155L, 74L, 120L, 58L, 276L, 38L, 
92L, 72L, 25L, 40L, 123L), "11-15" = c(31L, 11L, 33L, 15L, 19L, 
188L, 52L, 127L, 66L, 102L, 50L, 241L, 26L, 74L, 72L, 26L, 35L, 
68L), "12-15" = c(34L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 17L, 205L, 80L, 150L, 73L, 
109L, 50L, 228L, 29L, 57L, 59L, 14L, 45L, 93L), "1-16" = c(20L, 
9L, 25L, 21L, 11L, 199L, 46L, 124L, 65L, 117L, 40L, 224L, 28L, 
88L, 43L, 22L, 18L, 94L), "2-16" = c(54L, 11L, 29L, 20L, 11L, 
164L, 44L, 117L, 70L, 85L, 46L, 192L, 23L, 89L, 50L, 27L, 29L, 
86L), "3-16" = c(53L, 11L, 24L, 26L, 19L, 203L, 45L, 144L, 66L, 
109L, 47L, 213L, 15L, 120L, 59L, 15L, 33L, 127L)), .Names = c("LSOA Name", 
"3-15", "4-15", "5-15", "6-15", "7-15", "8-15", "9-15", "10-15", 
"11-15", "12-15", "1-16", "2-16", "3-16"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please dput(yourDataframe) or a section

Comment: Should be there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way of plotting lines by groups in ggplot is to shift the data to long format, where one column identifies the group, and the other columns identify the x and y axis values.

This example shifts your data into long format with three columns: LSOAName, month_col, and values_col. It adds a day value onto the month-year, and converts that column to a date. Then it plots a line for each group.

I've renamed your dataframe d, because dataframe could be easily misinterpreted as the function data.frame().

```
# load libraries
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


# rename dataframe so it doesn't look so much like the base function
d <- dataframe

# remove spaces in column names
names(d) <- gsub(" ", "", names(d))

# shift data from wide to long and then
# add a day value and convert day-month-year to date class
d %<>% gather(month_col, values_col, -LSOAName) %>%
  mutate(month_col = as.Date(paste0("1-", month_col), "%d-%m-%y"))

# plot using ggplot2
ggplot(d, aes(x = month_col, y = values_col, colour = LSOAName)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

#### Edit

%<>% is found in the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package. It is a compound pipe assignment operator. While %>% returns the result of a pipeline, %<>% assigns the result back to the left side object.

Instead of writing

```
d <- d %>% [pipeline]
```

you can assign the results to d by writing

```
d %<>% [pipeline]
```

Comment: Note taken. Thanks @Gregor.